# Why this integral is $0$? $ \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{2 \cos(2t) (\sqrt{2}ie^{it})}{4e^{i4t}-2\sqrt{2}e^{i2t}+1}dt$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I was unable to calculate this integral directly $$ \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{2 \cos(2t) (\sqrt{2}ie^{it})}{4e^{i4t}-2\sqrt{2}e^{i2t}+1}dt$$

so I put it into wolfram and it says that it is equal to zero. Does anyone know why?

**EDIT**:

The original integral was $$\int_{|z| = \sqrt{2}} \frac{\operatorname{Re}(z^2)}{z^4-\sqrt{2}z^2+1} dz$$ and I did the substitution $z = \sqrt{2}e^{it}$.

Comment: I suppose the original integral's domain should be $\;|z|=\sqrt2\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio yes, typo error, sorry

Comment: That isn't an analytic function because of the numerator and thus residues and stuff don't wokr here

Comment: The command of Mathematica `Integrate[
   2*Cos[2*t]*Sqrt[2]*I*
    Exp[I*t]/(4*Exp[I*4 t] - 2*Sqrt[2]*Exp[I*2*t] + 1), {t, 0, 
    2*Pi}] // ComplexExpand // FullSimplify` performs $0$ and the numeric calculation `NIntegrate[
  2*Cos[2*t]*Sqrt[2]*I*
    Exp[I*t]/(4*Exp[I*4 t] - 2*Sqrt[2]*Exp[I*2*t] + 1) + 1, {t, 0, 
   2*Pi}] - 2*Pi` confirms it. The commad `Integrate[    2*Cos[2*t]*Sqrt[2]*I*     Exp[I*t]/(4*Exp[I*4 t] - 2*Sqrt[2]*Exp[I*2*t] + 1), {t, 0,      2*Pi}] ` produces a big and complicated  expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the $e^{it}$ factor, the integrand multiplies by $-1$ when you apply $t\mapsto t+\pi$ (i.e. $z\mapsto-z$), so the $[\pi,\,2\pi]$ part of the integral cancels the $[0,\,\pi]$ part (as long as you can show it's finite).

Alternative argument:

Note that $\left|z\right|=\sqrt{2}\implies\Re\left(z^{2}\right)=\frac{z^{2}+4z^{-2}}{2}$. Since $f\left(z\right):=\frac{z^{4}+4}{2z^{2}\left(z^{4}-\sqrt{2}z^{2}+1\right)}$ has a second-order pole $0$ and a set $S$ of first-order poles closed under $z\mapsto-z$,$$\oint_{\left|z\right|=2}f\left(z\right)dz=2\pi i\left(\lim_{z\to0}\frac{d}{dz}\left(z^{2}f\left(z\right)\right)+\sum_{w\in S}\lim_{z\to w}\left(z-w\right)f\left(z\right)\right).$$Since $\lim_{z\to-w}\left(z+w\right)f\left(z\right)=-\lim_{z\to w}\left(z-w\right)f\left(z\right)$ because $f$ is even, poles in $S$ don't contribute. But $\frac{d}{dz}\left(z^{2}f\left(z\right)\right)$ is odd, with $z\to0$ limit $0$, so the integral is $0$. Or if you want to be explicit,$$\frac{d}{dz}\frac{z^{4}+4}{2\left(z^{4}-\sqrt{2}z^{2}+1\right)}=\frac{2z^{3}}{z^{4}-\sqrt{2}z^{2}+1}-\frac{z\left(z^{2}-\sqrt{2}\right)\left(z^{4}+4\right)}{\left(z^{4}-\sqrt{2}z^{2}+1\right)^{2}}.$$

Comment: @DonAntonio Well, by "changes sign" I mean "multiplies by $-1$". The $e^{it}$ factor is the culprit. I've edited my answer to clarify these.

Comment: @uniquesolution Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @J.G. what do you mean by "a set of poles closed under $z \mapsto -z$ "?

Comment: @J.G. the original integral was on $|z| = \sqrt{2}$, not on $|z| = 2$, does this make any difference?

Comment: @zuzu I mean if $z\in S$ then $-z\in S$. No, any positive radius will achieve the same thing. More generally, integrating an even function around a centre-$0$ circle gives $0$.

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$\int_{|z| = \sqrt{2}} \frac{\operatorname{Re}(z^2)}{z^4-\sqrt{2}z^2+1} dz
=\int_{|z| = \sqrt{2}} \frac{z^2/2+2/z^2}{z^4-\sqrt{2}z^2+1} dz
=\int_{|z| = R} \frac{z^2/2+2/z^2}{z^4-\sqrt{2}z^2+1} dz
$$
for any $R>1$ (as the singularities are in the closed unit disk). Let $R\rightarrow +\infty$ and you obtain the wanted result.

Comment: +1. Nice, but somewhat tricky.